# Xamarin ExportRenderer could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a custom renderer for an advert

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
using FreeFallCalculator.Controls;
using FreeFallCalculator.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms.Internals;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdControlView), typeof(AdViewRenderer))]
namespace FreeFallCalculator.Models
{
    class AdViewRenderer
    {

    }
}
```

It keeps giving me this error when trying to compile:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ExportRendererAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is the renderer in the Droid or ios project? It looks like it isn't. That is where the ExportRenderer attribute is generally used.

Comment: it's also a little weird to have a Renderer in a "Models" namespace

Comment: Please refer to : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Answer (score 2):

The custom renderer should be in the platform specific project.

Answer (score 0):

And your `ClassRenderer` you need inherit `PageRenderer`then:

```
class AdViewRenderer: PageRenderer //never forget
{

}
```

this for each platform